# How to quit ircII help session?

Tags: linux, irc

I'm using [ircII](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IrcII) as my irc client to chat on irc channels.

As I'm new to this terminal based program so I tend to use `/help` command very frequently. The problem is when I go in help session I get trapped there. Few things I tried (while in help session) are:

- `quit`

Which shows me help for quit.

- `quit` (again)

Asks `Do you really want to quit?`

Well when I do `y` here the entire ircii is quit.

Answer (score 1):

If the "Help?" prompt is show, you're being prompted to enter a term or command for which you want to see the help. Just pressing return (i.e. an empty input) will bring you up one level:

- If you type `/help`, the prompt will be "Help?";
- type `set` and you'll get the help for the set command, which has suboptions and a sub-help, so the command is now "set Help?";
- a single return brings you up to the top-level "Help?";
- another return exits the help completely (no prompt by default, or whatever you've configured your client to display).

(As an unrelated aside, ircII is quite dated and basic; it works fine, of course, but for a commandline client I advise you to investigate [irssi](http://irssi.org/).)